# BibTeX generates the same citation call-out for two publications

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing

I have two publications with the same author (same surname and same first initial) and year. Usually when this happens, BibTeX automatically appends an "a" or a "b" to distinguish the two. However, in this case, that is not the case. Here is what I've got:

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{bibliography, studies}
```

Bibtex:

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{usingbertto,  
    author={C. {Lin} and C. {Huang} and C. {Wu}}, 
    booktitle={2019 IEEE 20th International Conference on Information Reuse and Integration for Data Science (IRI)},
    title={{Using BERT to Process Chinese Ellipsis and Coreference in Clinic Dialogues}},   
    year={2019},  
    volume={},  
    number={},  
    pages={414-418},  
    doi={10.1109/IRI.2019.00070}
}

@inproceedings{abertbaseduniversal,
    title = {A {BERT}-based universal model for both within-and cross-sentence clinical temporal relation extraction},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of the 2nd {Clinical} {Natural} {Language} {Processing} {Workshop}},
    author = {Lin, Chen and Miller, Timothy and Dligach, Dmitriy and Bethard, Steven and Savova, Guergana},
    year = {2019},
    pages = {65--71}
}
```

Both papers are referenced with the citation [Lin et al., 2019]. Is there any way to make BibTeX distinguish between the two?

Comment: You didn'r say how you are processing the bib information, but I would first try giving full first names to both papers, or using first initials in both.

Comment: Take the `{...}` out of the names in entries like your first one, and put them in the `.bib` file consistently as LastName, FirstName. And don't put punctuation in the `.bib` file (e.g. your `.` after the initial in the first one.) As @DonaldArseneau says, you need to be consistent with initials or full first names (although in reality this should match what's actually in the journal, since some authors only publish with initials.)  Full names are generally better, since styles can turn full names into initials, but (obviously) not the other way around.

Comment: But to answer your question more directly, we can't tell you how to disambiguate differing multiple authors without knowing what how you are actually producing your citations, which you don't tell us.

Comment: Please tell us which bibliography style you employ. And, do please tell us whether you use a citation management package such as `natbib`.

Comment: Aplogies, apalike, just edited.

Comment: As Alan says: The `{...}` around the names are the problem. While the `{...}`s are not visible in the output when the text is rendered by TeX, `Lin` and `{Lin}` are two different names for BIbTeX when it does its disambiguation. The braces serve no practical purpose in this case and should be removed.

Comment: Thanks guys, I fixed the ```{...}``` and that solved it. Much appreciated!